# Why isn't there a formSubtracting() method in Swift for Sets

Tags: swift, methods, set

In Swift there is a Form... equivalent for the Sets methods `intersection()`, `symmetricDifference()` and `union()`, i.e. `formIntersection()`, `formSymmetricDifference()` and `formUnion()`.

But for the method `subtracting()` there is no method called `formSubtracting`. Does anyone know why this is so, because it seams I now have to use something like `mySet = mySet.subtracting(anotherSet)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`subtract(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1779475-subtract) is what you are looking for:

> Removes the elements of the given set from this set.

Example:

```
var mySet: Set = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let anotherSet : Set = [2, 4, 6, 8]
mySet.subtract(anotherSet)
print(mySet) // [3, 1, 5]
```

There is also a [variant](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/2853597-subtract) which takes another *sequence* (of the same element type) as the argument, e.g. an array:

```
var mySet: Set = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let anotherSequence = [2, 4, 6, 8]
mySet.subtract(anotherSequence)
print(mySet) // [3, 1, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Completely overlooked it. And still thinking that there is some inconsistency between the subtract method and the other three...